# using terraform .12.10+ templatefile function to populate local_secrets to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

Can anyone help me on how i can use `templatefile` function in terraform .12.10+ to populate local_secrets to S3 bucket .

```
locals {
  prefix = join("-", [var.prefix, "core"])
  common_tags = merge(var.common_tags, map("Stack", "ipolls-core"))
  core_secrets = merge(var.secrets, map("AWS_REGION", data.aws_region.current.name,
      "AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME", aws_s3_bucket.assets.bucket,
      "AWS_S3_FQDN", join(".", [aws_s3_bucket.assets.bucket, "s3", data.aws_region.current.name, "amazonaws", "com"]),
      "AWS_STATIC_ASSETS_LOCATION", element(var.s3_objects, index(var.s3_objects,"static")),
      "AWS_MEDIA_ASSETS_LOCATION", element(var.s3_objects, index(var.s3_objects,"media")),
      "STATIC_URL", join("", ["https://", local.core_secrets["AWS_S3_FQDN"], "/", local.core_secrets["AWS_STATIC_ASSETS_LOCATION"], "/"]),
      "MEDIA_URL", join("", ["https://", local.core_secrets["AWS_S3_FQDN"], "/", local.core_secrets["AWS_MEDIA_ASSETS_LOCATION"], "/"]),
      "AWS_DEFAULT_ACL", "None"))
  images_dir = join("/", [path.module, "images"])
}
```

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "envs" {
  bucket = var.s3_settings["bucket"]
  key = join("/", [local.prefix, "env"])
  acl = "private"
  for_each = local.core_secrets
  content = templatefile(join("/", [path.module, "templates", "envs.tpl"]), { each.key = each.value })
}
```

can I use `for_each` function to iterate the `secrets` map, and how i can configure `envs.tpl` file to read `each.key and each.value`

Comment: What happened when you tried to use the configuration you shared here? How was that different than what you expected? (Please edit your question with that additional information, rather than adding a comment.)

Comment: Hello Martin, actually I couldn't use `for_each` here as it gives an error while running `terraform plan` because `for_each` requires all the information to be known in advance. so i changed the way to populate the secrets to AWS SeccretManager

Answer (score 0):

A new approach is used to activate the same thing `populate APP secrets to app container`
So, in here I created an `AWS_SECRET_MANAGER` to store the SECRETS from `local.core_secrets` and on the container, I will retrieve the Keys via the entrypoint

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secrets" {
  name = join("-", [local.prefix, "secret"])
  description = "secret store to store app secrets"
  kms_key_id = var.kms
  tags  = merge(local.common_tags, map("Type", "SecretManager"))
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secrets" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets.arn
  secret_string = jsonencode(local.core_secrets)
}
```